# Super Basic OpenFileDialog in C++/CLI is throwing error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, c++-cli

```
OpenFileDialog^ dialog = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
dialog->ShowDialog();
```

What could possibly be wrong with this?
I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional on Windows 7 with .NET Framework 3.5
I created a button and added a Click Function and I put the above code, and just throw this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

I translated it from Portuguese to English since my Visual Studio threw the error in portuguese.

> Additional information: The current thread should be defined in STA
>   Mode (Single Thread Apartment ) before OLE calls can be done. Check if
>   the Main Function has STAThreadAttribute checked. The Exception will
>   only be generated if the debugger is attached to the thread (or maybe
>   process).

and this is the original error in Portuguese Language:

> Additional information: O thread atual deve ser definido no modo STA
>   (single thread apartment) antes que chamadas OLE possam ser feitas.
>   Verifique se a função Main tem STAThreadAttribute marcado. A exceção
>   somente será gerada se um depurador estiver anexado ao processo.

By the way, all microsoft default stuff is set, all libraries that Windows Forms Application preset when creating a project, 
I hope I was clear enough
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's asking for you to put:

[STAThread]

on your main function. This means that clr should start a Single Threaded Apartment. Windows Forms wont work in a MTA (Multithreaded Apartment).

Further reading here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/04/07/406341.aspx